# Trouble duplicating a matrix over indices of an array

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble with duplicating a matrix over indices of an array. Here is a simplified version of my problem. I don't understand what R is doing here...

```
test_array <- array(NA, c(4,3,2))
test_matrix <- as.matrix(data.frame(rep(1, 4),rep(2, 4)))
test_array[,1:3,] <- test_matrix  # I want this matrix duplicated across this array such that the below commands print the exact same result: the test_matrix
test_array[,1,]
test_array[,2,] # What's going on here?
test_array[,3,]
```

What have I missed? And if the above doesn't work, then why does the below work just fine?

```
test_array <- array(NA, c(4,3,3))
test_matrix <- as.matrix(data.frame(rep(1, 4),rep(2, 4),rep(3, 4)))
test_array[,,1:3] <- test_matrix
test_array[,,1]
test_array[,,2]
test_array[,,3]
```

And this also works fine, but I'd really rather not loop it:

```
test_array <- array(NA, c(4,3,2))
test_matrix <- as.matrix(data.frame(rep(1, 4),rep(2, 4)))
test_array[,1,] <- test_matrix
test_array[,2,] <- test_matrix
test_array[,3,] <- test_matrix
test_array[,1,]
test_array[,2,]
test_array[,3,]
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this has to do with R's recycling rules. If you look at `test_array` after initialization you see the following output:

```r
test_array <- array(NA, c(4,3,2))
test_matrix <- t(matrix(1:2, nrow = 2, ncol = 4))

test_array
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   NA   NA
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA
```

Now your `test_matrix` looks like this:

```r
test_matrix
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    1    2
# [3,]    1    2
# [4,]    1    2
```

Now if you want to store this into `test_array[, 1:3, ]` (which is by the way the same as `test_array`) R duplicates the matrix such that it fits the dimensions. That is each odd column will be a column filled with 1s and each even column filled with 2s (the first column of the second matrix can be seen as the 4th column overall if this helps to understand).

That is if you ask for `test_array[, 1, ]` you will get the first column of each matrix.

Now why does it work if you use a single index? This is b/c R silently drops dimensions if possible unless you specify `drop = FALSE`:

```r
dim(test_array[, 1, ])
# [1] 4 2
dim(test_array[, 1:3, ])
# [1] 4 3 2
dim(test_array[, 1, , drop = FALSE])
# [1] 4 1 2
```

Overall, in the assignment case, if you use more than one column, R needs to do some recycling to fit dimensions, while for a single column the dimensions fit and no recycling is needed.

---

To solve it, you need to replicate your test matrix to account for the last dimension:

```r
r <- rep(test_matrix, each = 3)
dim(r) <- dim(test_array)

test_array[, 1:3, ] <- r
test_array
# , , 1
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    1    1
# 
# , , 2
# 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    2    2
# [2,]    2    2    2
# [3,]    2    2    2
# [4,]    2    2    2
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation @thothal! Thanks to you, I understand. So glad I don't have to loop this.